# appling different styles based on taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms, theming

I have a site with 120 categories of content. I've used taxonomy to make these categories. now I need to have some different styles base on the taxonomy which is used in nodes. OK? how can I do it.

I need something like page--article.tpl.php which you use to have different styles for different content types. but here I want to separate styles based on taxonomy

as my website is very big and heavy and has 700k visitors daily, I avoid using modules like panels or context! this modules will kill my site's performance and speed! so I need simple approach without using modules.

Comment: Not quite clear what are you trying to do. Do you want to have separate *templates* per each taxonomy term?

Comment: I have some contents each in just one category. the category is defined by taxonomy. now I want each content have a style based on its category. for example if a content has food taxonomy the the whole style is one thing and if it has drinking taxonomy the whole style is another one. am I clear?

Comment: Not still; by saying *style* do you mean CSS class applied to the `body` element, or a separate template?

Comment: I actually mean both! In some cases some changes in colors are enough but in some other taxonomies I need a completely different template. it is more about making templates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have specific template files by using [theme hook suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656). To change the **node template**, use the following:

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $node = $vars['node'];

  // Perform this only on certain content types.
  if ($node->type == 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE') {

    // get the taxonomy term (node category)
    $tid  = $node->field_YOURTERM[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'];
    $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
    $term_name = drupal_html_class($term->name);

    // add a css class with the category's name
    $vars['classes_array'][] = 'node-category-' . $term_name;

    // make drupal search for category-specific node templates
    // template files need to be named node--nodetype--termname.tpl.php
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__' . $node->type.'__' . $term_name;
  }
}
```

Say your categories are like "Drink Wine", the `$term_name` would be "drink-wine". Lowercarse, no spaces. You can remove `__$node->type` if you want.

To change the **page** template, use the following:

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $node = (isset($vars['node']) ? $vars['node'] : null);

  // Perform this only on certain content types.
  if ($node && $node->type == 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE') {

    // get the taxonomy term (node category)
    $tid  = $node->field_YOURTERM[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'];
    $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
    $term_name = drupal_html_class($term->name);

    // add a css class with the category's name
    $vars['classes_array'][] = 'page-node-category-' . $term_name;

    // make drupal search for category-specific page templates
    // template files need to be named page--nodetype--termname.tpl.php
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $node->type.'__' . $term_name;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Topsitemakers thanks for the `$node->type` filter, I was lazy :d

Comment: thanks a lot! I wanted to change the whole style so I change the last line to `$vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $node->type.'__' . $term_name;`. but now i see an error: _Notice: Undefined variable: site_logo in include() (line 16 of ..\templates\page--article--drinking.tpl.php)._ and a lot of such errors. but apparently it is using the new style file but what about the error?

Comment: Changing the whole page can be done the exact same way but using hook_preprocess_page instead. I'll update the code.

Comment: wow! you are right! I know about that. I should use this function instead: `function corolla_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook)`. thanks thanks thanks!!!

Comment: in preprocess page you need a check for $vars['node'], see my code above

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "***[taxonomy-term.tpl.php](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656)***" Theme Hook in Drupal 7. By copying the "***ROOT_DIRECTORY\modules\taxonomy\taxonomy-term.tpl.php***" into your theme template directory will override, and rename the file with your Vocabulary Machine Name(taxonomy-term--machinename.tpl.php).

Comment: He wants to theme node that have an given term attached to them, not to theme terms themselves.